# DISTINCT with ORDER BY very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am using postgres for the first time and finding it rather slow to run distinct and group by queries, currently i am trying to find the latest record and whether or not it is working or not.
This is the first query I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (device_id) c.device_id, c.timestamp, c.working
         FROM call_logs c
         ORDER BY c.device_id, c.timestamp desc
```

And it works but it is taking along time to run.

```
 Unique  (cost=94840.24..97370.54 rows=11 width=17) (actual time=424.424..556.253 rows=13 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=94840.24..96105.39 rows=506061 width=17) (actual time=424.423..531.905 rows=506061 loops=1)
     Sort Key: device_id, "timestamp" DESC
     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13272kB
     ->  Seq Scan on call_logs c  (cost=0.00..36512.61 rows=506061 width=17) (actual time=0.059..162.932 rows=506061 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.152 ms
 Execution time: 557.957 ms
(7 rows)
```

I have updated the query to use the following which is faster but very ugly:

```
SELECT c.device_id, c.timestamp, c.working FROM call_logs c
  INNER JOIN (SELECT c.device_id, MAX(c.timestamp) AS timestamp
                                              FROM call_logs c
                                              GROUP BY c.device_id)
                                              newest on newest.timestamp = c.timestamp
```

and the analysis:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=39043.34..39136.08 rows=12 width=17) (actual time=216.406..216.580 rows=15 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=39042.91..39043.02 rows=11 width=16) (actual time=216.347..216.351 rows=13 loops=1)
     Group Key: c_1.device_id
     ->  Seq Scan on call_logs c_1  (cost=0.00..36512.61 rows=506061 width=16) (actual time=0.026..125.482 rows=506061 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using call_logs_timestamp on call_logs c  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=13)
     Index Cond: ("timestamp" = (max(c_1."timestamp")))
 Planning time: 0.318 ms
 Execution time: 216.631 ms
(8 rows)
```

Even 200ms does seem a little slow to me as all I want is the top record per device (which is in an indexed table)

AND this is my index it is using:

```
CREATE INDEX call_logs_timestamp
ON public.call_logs USING btree
(timestamp)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I have tried the below index but does not help at all:

```
CREATE INDEX dev_ts_1
ON public.call_logs USING btree
(device_id, timestamp DESC, working)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Any ideas am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

200 ms really isn't that bad for going through 500k rows.  But for this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (device_id) c.device_id, c.timestamp, c.working
FROM call_logs c
ORDER BY c.device_id, c.timestamp desc
```

Then your index on `call_logs(device_id, timestamp desc, working)` should be an optimal index.

Two other ways to write the query for the same index are:

```
select c.*
from (select c.device_id, c.timestamp, c.working, c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from call_logs c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

and:

```
select c.device_id, c.timestamp, c.working
from call_logs c
where not exists (select 1
                  from call_logs c2
                  where c2.device_id = c.device_id and
                        c2.timestamp > c.timestamp
                 );
```

Comment: The index is not being used. But I am unsure what you mean by an optimal index?

Comment: @user1434177 . . . Optimal means that is the best index for the query.  Perhaps the statistics are not correct on the table.

Comment: Thank you I used VACUUM ANALYZE; and it now takes 74ms to run.